# Nice way to calculate the inverse of a block matrix that consists of a matrix and a vector?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse, matrix-equations, block-matrices

is there a nice way to calculate the inverse of the following matrix symbolically?

$A\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n+1}$ and $b\in\mathbb{R}^{1\times n+1}$
so that $B=\left(\begin{array}{c}A\\b \end{array}\right)\in\mathbb{R}^{n+1\times n+1}$ are given. 
Is there a nice way to express the inverse of B , inv(B) or is that not possible?

Answer (score 0):

$$\begin{bmatrix} \mathrm A\,\,\\ \mathrm b^{\top}\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} \mathrm X & \mathrm y\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} \mathrm I_n & 0_n\\ 0_n^{\top} & 1\end{bmatrix}$$

produces $4$ linear matrix equations. [Vectorizing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vectorization_(mathematics)), we obtain the following linear system

$$\left( \begin{bmatrix} \mathrm I_n & 0_n\\ 0_n^{\top} & 1\end{bmatrix} \otimes \begin{bmatrix} \mathrm A\,\,\\ \mathrm b^{\top}\end{bmatrix} \right) \begin{bmatrix} \mbox{vec} (\mathrm X)\\ \mathrm y\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} \mbox{vec} (\mathrm I_n)\\ 0_n\\ 0_n\\ 1\end{bmatrix}$$